# Windows Forms in Powershell, select from multiple listview/boxes

Tags: winforms, powershell

My first try at using forms, I'm writing a small utility for the service desk to select GPO and home drives for new users. It uses two ListView and one Listbox.
I've got the form populated, but don't know how to allow selection/highlighting of one item from each listbox/listview simultaneously - the most I can get is one Listview and the Listbox - if I select an item from the lower box the upper one is no longer highlighted:

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direciton please? The searches I'm using are coming up with how to select multiple from one listbox/view.

Code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Basic form setup

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'NSS New User Setup'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,600)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$form.MaximizeBox = $false

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,530)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(325,530)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,20)
$label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label1.Text = 'Select user GPO group for drives and settings'
$form.Controls.Add($label1)

$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,250)
$label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label2.Text = 'Select user Home Drive location:'
$form.Controls.Add($label2)

$label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(210,20)
$label3.Text = 'Enter user name/UID and click "Search"'
$form.Controls.Add($label3)

$label4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,65)
$label4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(210,20)
$label4.Text = 'Select User'
$form.Controls.Add($label4)

$label5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,480)
$label5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(210,20)
$label5.Text = 'Current Settings:'
$form.Controls.Add($label5)

# List of GPOs

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$listBox.Height = 200
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*GPO Drives*"} | Sort Name | ForEach {
    [void] $listBox.Items.Add($_.Name)
}

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)

# List of User/UIDs

$UIDlist = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$UIDlist.View = 'Details'
$UIDlist.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,85)
$UIDlist.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(285,20)
$UIDlist.Height = 155
$UIDlist.Columns.Add('SamAccountName') | Out-Null
$UIDlist.Columns.Add('Name') | Out-Null
$UIDlist.FullRowSelect = $true
$UIDlist.AutoResizeColumns([System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle]::HeaderSize)

$form.Controls.Add($UIDlist)

# List of Home Drive locations

$listView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$listView.View = 'Details'
$listView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,270)
$listView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560,15)
$listView.Height = 200
$listView.Columns.Add('HomePath') | Out-Null
$listView.Columns.Add('Usage') | Out-Null
$listView.Columns.Add('Description') | Out-Null

$ValidNewHomes | ForEach {
    $Entry = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.HomePath)
    $Entry.SubItems.Add($_.Usage) | Out-Null
    $Entry.SubItems.Add($_.Description) | Out-Null
    $listView.Items.Add($Entry) | Out-Null
}


$listView.AutoResizeColumns([System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle]::ColumnContent)

$form.Controls.Add($listView)

# Add Entry field for userID search

$UIDentry = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Textbox
$UIDEntry.Location='10,40'
$UIDentry.Size = '200,1000'
$form.Controls.Add($UIDEntry)


$SearchButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$SearchButton.Location = '220,38'
$SearchButton.Size = '75,23'
$SearchButton.Text = 'Search'
# Event handler to handle the button being clicked
$SearchButton.Add_Click({
    $UIDlist.Items.Clear()
    $RequestedUID = $UIDentry.Text
    $PossibleUserList = Validate-User $RequestedUID
    $PossibleUserList | ForEach {
        $UIDresult = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.SamAccountName)
        $UIDresult.SubItems.Add($_.Name) | Out-Null
        $UIDlist.Items.Add($UIDresult) | Out-Null
        $UIDlist.Columns[1].([System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle]::ColumnContent)
    }
})
# $form.Button = $SearchButton
$form.Controls.Add($SearchButton)


$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()
```

#

Comment: By the lack of response, it's either tough to do, or not possible... I was hoping to aloow users to just highlight and click OK - looks like I'll have to use an "Apply" button instead